# UUID mapping to bitset

Tags: java

There're many UUID which has 128bit, I want to set every UUID as a integer and flag it in bitset's each position. But It seems 128bit is too long.

How can I implement this function and there is no collision?

Answer (score 2):

By using bitset, you will need 2^128 which is around 3.4 x 10^38 bits.

You want something that cost you less memory, it is possible.  But if you want it to have absolutely no collision, it is impossible, simply by pigeon hole principle.

But why you want it to be "no collision"? For example, if you are going to use `HashMap`, a relatively normal hashing function, plus pre-initializing the HashMap to the expected size is going to save you a lot of collision.  And even there are some collisions, I don't think it will be a big impact to performance (unless the hashing method is really poorly done).

---

A workaround if your "add to bitset" is explicit (hence you do not need to determine if a UUID is already in the bit set):

Assuming you need to store status of 100,000,000 devices, you will need at least 100,000,000 bits.

By using a reasonable hashing algorithm, make up a 27 bit hash, and the hash will determine which bit to use to store the status.  Hence you will need a bitmap of 2^27 =134,217,728 bits ~=17MB.

Have 2 `BitSet`s of such size (cost you around 34MB), one for keeping status, one for keeping "availability of bit".

Have a extra `Map<UUID, Integer>` as "exceptional device bit"

For a new UUID, calculate that 27bit hash. If the result value is not occupied in "bitAvailabilityBitset", turn that on.

For a new UUID, if the hash result is occupied in "bitAvailabilityBitSet", find the index of next unoccupied bit, turn that on in "bitAvailabilityBitSet", and add the UUID + index pair in "exceptional device bit" map.

Doing something in reverse when lookup/update: first check if UUID is in "exceptional device bit" map, if so, use the index in the map to lookup.  If not, simply calculate the 27bit hash as the index to lookup

Given a relatively good hashing algorithm, the collision should not be frequent and hence, the extra overhead for that "exceptional device bit" map should not be big.  You may further adjust the size of the bitset to tradeoff size for reduction of collision

Comment: Actually, the UUID represents a device, I want to use bitset to store all devices's status. Eash position of bitset represents one device, the value 0 or 1 represents the status. I don't have a sequence id for each device, only UUID.

Comment: Why can't you use a HashMap then?  And what you said have no effect on my reasoning.

Comment: Or simply a HashSet.  Existence in set means turned on, else means off

Comment: I want to use the EWAH compressed bitmap object to store more data with less size.

Comment: How many "devices" you are aiming to handle? It seems to me it is more like pre-mature optimization

Comment: 10~100 millions, and one bitmap object can store 2^32-1 bit status.

Comment: Unless you know which 100 million 128bit integer you are going to use, it is meaningless to talk about 2^32-1.  By using a bitmap, you need to prepare for all the possible values, hence you will need 2^128 bits

Comment: and, I am not sure what do you mean by "one bitmap object".  You can have any number of bits you want.  If you are talking about a 32-bit bitmap, then I think you are wrong.  32bit can only holds 32 statuses

Comment: I wonder how efficient and how much less memory can a compressed 2^128 bit Bitset can be.  It will be great if you can share your study on that

Comment: EWAH is a compressed bitmap library, which like the Java Bitset with compressed feature. It really support 2^32 bit:)  Let me describe the problem from another way, although the device id has 128 bit, but I only have max 100 million devices, this number is less than 2^32. So I think it can store all devices' 2 status. so I want to know is it possible to find a way to map one device to one bit position in bitmap object.

Comment: I know what EWAH is, what I said is, unless you know beforehand all the UUIDs you are going to put in, you cannot use a bitset < 2^128 bits without any possible collision base on pigeon hole principle.  If you can manage to find such way, you do not need any compression like EWAH, as I have pointed out, you only need around 17 MB for a bitset large enough.  In theory, if you know all the UUIDs beforehand, you can always find a way to calculate a perfect hash but I doubt if it is true for  your case.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can not know all UUID beforehand. any IDs are possible.  When the count of devices are not so high, I store them in database and auto-increment primary key will be generated and a unique integer can represent one device and can be used for bit position in bitmap. But when the data is huge and in distributed system, it's hard to use this method, I don't know if there is other solution about this.

Comment: Thanks. I get your point. Your solution is a box, the input is UUID and the output is an Int32. It seems well. Now I try to implement it to support high traffic concurrent calls. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: I find a bug from your solution. If UUID A and B has the same hash result, they will occupy the same position. If A is first came into system, the position is occupied. and hashmap object doesn't have it. Next, when A or B is coming, the whole system can not identify who it is. For A, the hash result is occupied, and no else info in hashmap. For B, it is still the same hash result, and no info in hashmap. How can the solution to do?

Comment: my logic based on the assumption that you know you are adding a new entry (e.g. during system initialization), instead of relying on the map to tell you if an entry exists and you insert/update accordingly.  If you can't tell the full set of entry initially, how are you supposed to create a bitset that you know is big enough?

Comment: The full set can be estimated appropriately, such as no more than 1 billions(less than Integer.Max) which bases on the actual environment. We don't know wether it is a new entry. I tried put a bloomfilter before your solution, that can be useful, but still can not avoid collision.